# Pubby doesn´t show xsd:double. (semantic web & opendata)

Tags: html, double, semantic-web, virtuoso

I have a Virtuoso Server to serve triples about domotical sensors. There is a pubby configured to resolve the URIS of the resources.

Let´s consider a device, which has the following triples:

```
@prefix ddb: <http://opendata.intellidomo.es/ontologiadomoticabd#> .
@prefix xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#> .
@prefix rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> .
@prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> .

<http://opendata.intellidomo.es/recursos/dispositivos/219>
  ddb:hasCodigoUnidad 1 ;
  ddb:hasValor "0.0"^^xsd:double ;
  ddb:hasTipoDatos <http://opendata.intellidomo.es/recursos/tipodato/6> ;
  rdfs:comment "SensorX10" ;
  a ddb:MotionSensor ;
  ddb:hasProtocolo "x10" ;
  a ddb:Device ;
  rdfs:label "SensorX10" ;
  ddb:hasCodigoCasa "A" ;
  ddb:#hasMapa <http://opendata.intellidomo.es/recursos/mapa/Plano%20Casa> .
```

Here is a snapshot of the content we find if we introduce the URI of the resource (http://opendata.intellidomo.es/recursos/dispositivos/219 ) in a browser:

[image]
<sub>(source: [semanticweb.com](https://answers.semanticweb.com//upfiles/Captura_de_pantalla_2013-05-15_a_la(s)_12.04.47.png))</sub>

Why does the property "hasValor" have the value NAN ()???

If I get the triples from virtuoso directly they are correct, the type of hasValor is xsd:double, and the value is 0.0; which is correct. But when I see the Pubby, or download the triples from Pubby, then it doesn´t show the correct value :"0.0"^^xsd:double, it shows: NAN ().

I have tried with other types like xsd:float but the outcome is the same. Any suggestions?

Comment: Sorry for being such a screwup

Answer (score 0):

If querying the data directly via the Virtuoso SPARQL Endpoint (/sparql), then the problem would appear to be in Pubby ?

What is the version of Virtuoso being used:

virtuoso-t -?

Comment: yes, I am using virtuoso-t. ---- 
The endpoint is http://158.49.245.76:8890/sparql (remember to use the GRAPH http://opendata.intellidomo.es/recursos/ ). ------ 
To see the values you can use this sentence: select ?value FROM <http://opendata.intellidomo.es/recursos/>  where {[] ddb:hasValor ?value} LIMIT 100  -----


It is a bit weird because the type "double" is not shown in the HTML format, but if I choose RDF as outcome the retrieved document contains: <res:value datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#double">0.0</res:value> ---
Which make me think that the endpoint is not the problem.